# laravel orWhere giving unexpected result when value is false

Tags: php, laravel

I wrote a query

```
Order::where(function ($query) use ($request) {
      $query->where('email', $request->email_or_mobile)
            ->orWhere('mobile_no', $request->email_or_mobile);
    })
    ->where('transaction_no', $request->reference_no)
    ->count();
```

This query is ok when `$request->email_or_mobile` is not `false`. but when `false` it skip

```
where(function ($query) use ($request) {
      $query->where('email', $request->email_or_mobile)
            ->orWhere('mobile_no', $request->email_or_mobile);
    })
```

and gives result of `->where('transaction_no', $request->reference_no)` condition. Why I get this wired behavior ?

Comment: what is your expected result or query you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

When your `$request->email_or_mobile` is false you will have a condition `false == false`  in your sql, which results in true,  so your sql will be like this
`SELECT * FROM order WHERE (false = false) and transaction_no=?`, this means that the orders will be filtered only by transaction_no.

Answer (score -1):

```
Order::where('email', $request->email_or_mobile)
    ->orWhere(function($query) use ($request) {
            ->Where('mobile_no', $request->email_or_mobile);
    })
    ->where('transaction_no', $request->reference_no)
    ->count();
```

Try This.

Comment: Why should the OP ___try this___? **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer. If it is well answered maybe they will UpVote it.